# React-Native Android: Unable to display static images

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display a static image(ic_launcher) in my android app using react native. I am getting a black response. No errors. Just a blank view as though the resource doesn't exist.I am able to display images from the network.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ic_launcher files are probably placed in android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxx directories. Try to move it to android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxx directories.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- \android
- |----\app
- |----|---\src
- |----|---|----\main
- |----|---|----|---\res
- |----|---|----|---|---\drawable
- |----|---|----|---|---|---\ic_launcher.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use `require('image!img_name')` as a `source` attribute of `Image` component.
See example app here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/ImageExample.js#L84 with it's resource placed under https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/res/drawable